# Adding Series in multiple chart Areas

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a chart with multiple chart areas and I want each time a new chart area is selected, the listview to reset, and the user to be able to add as many series he wants in the new area.

I create new series each time an item from a listview is checked.
Here is what I have tried :

```
private void listView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        // checkedItems.Clear();
       
        chart1.Series.Add((listView1.Items[e.Index].Text).ToString());
        checkedItems.Add(chart1.Series[(listView1.Items[e.Index].Text).ToString()]);
       
        foreach (var chitem in checkedItems)
        {
            chitem.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chitem.ChartArea = select; // select is the name of the selected chart Area
            for (int r = 0; r < num_rows; r++)
            {
                chitem.Points.AddXY(r,values[r,listView1.Items.IndexOf(listView1.Items[e.Index])]);
            }
        }
    }
}


private void chart1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ChartArea ca in chart1.ChartAreas)
        {
            
            if (ChartAreaClientRectangle(chart1, ca).Contains(e.Location))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" You have double-clicked on chartarea " + ca.Name);
                
                select = ca.Name;
                
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when the user selects another chart Area and therefore the select value is changing, all Series move from to the newest selected chart Area.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. The `chitem.ChartArea` property is a string and will not change just because you change the value of a variable. There must be other code that is responsible. How is `select` defined? Does it have a setter, perhaps..?

Comment: yes, select is defined in another function. The other function returns the name of the chart area that is double clicked.
I have not included it because I think it is not needed.

Comment: If that is all, then there should be other code that changes the `chitem.ChartArea` values.

Comment: I edited my question and added the missing code

Comment: Hm, just noticed that you a looping over all checked items, not just the newly item. This could be the reason why all previously and still checked items get assigned the new ca..

Comment: that's why I used checkedItems.Clear(); , in the first place, but it deletes all signals, and I need the number of Series plotted in each chart area

Comment: Well, I'm afraid you need to re-think your user interface and interactions.